# c# Convert an float to string in the form of 1E

Tags: c#

I am currently trying to convert a float to a particular format as a string.

If I have a float with a value of 0.000001, how do i maintain it's original format.

When I do something in the lines of

```
float f = 0.000001;
string s = f.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

I get an output 1E-06.
How do I keep this in the original form of 0.000001, not only for the example above, but with any float.

Also how would i get the strings to the format of 1EX instead of 0.00...1 if i need it.

Thank you

Comment: Side note: float (or any other numerical values) *do not* have "original format"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `R`, or *round trip* format string. This will write out the value as precisely as it can so that if necessary you can parse it back into a `float` and get the exact same value:

```
string s = f.ToString("R");
//Writes 0.000001
```

To write it out in scientific notation use the `E` format string:

```
string s = f.ToString("E");
//Writes 1E-06
```

[You can view all of the numeric format strings on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: When I attempt to put a "R" in the ToString is still shows is as the exponential mode, do you know why that may happen?

Answer (score 1):

```
float f = 0.000001f;
string s = f.ToString("#.#########", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
s = f.ToString("N" + s.Length);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: It would help if you added an explanation of why your answer might be correct.

Comment: I'm sorry I was at lunch hour and I catched your question the last minutes. What I'm doing is finding the length of the float (how many digits) then format the string based on that :)

Answer (score 1):

try .ToString("G"). MSDN gives the following explanation:

```
-123.456 ("G", en-US) -> -123.456
-123.456 ("G", sv-SE) -> -123,456
123.4546 ("G4", en-US) -> 123.5
123.4546 ("G4", sv-SE) -> 123,5
-1.234567890e-25 ("G", en-US) -> -1.23456789E-25
-1.234567890e-25 ("G", sv-SE) -> -1,23456789E-25
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'N' followed by the number of decimal places

```
float f = 0.000001F;
string s = f.ToString("N6");
```

Here you'll have 6 decimal places.